# Xamarin, trying to filter pins with a BindingContext, error: "requires an instance of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of pins and a filter so I can easily sort the pins. I currently sort them by adress (p.Adress) but I also would like to sort them by my BindingContext. When I add it in my code below it gives me this error: `Type "object" does not contain a member 'Contains' and the best extension method overload System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<string>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<string>, string) requires an instance of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'`

```
private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
    {
    map.Pins.Clear ();

    foreach(Pin p in myPins) {

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter) || (p.Address.Contains(filter))|| (p.BindingContext.Contains(filter))) {  //the bindingcontext is the one giving me the error.

                map.Pins.Add(p);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `p.BindingContext` does not implement IQueryable, so you can't use the extention method Contains. The type for `p.BindingContext` is `object`. Cast it to some other type that implements IQueryable and you'll be good to go.

Comment: yeah exactly, I was trying to do something like this: `p.BindingContext.Contains(filter)).ToString()` but it didnt work out. How could I adjust the code so it implements an IQueryable? I have not worked with that before.

Comment: Based on your prior question, you are not using data binding in your Map, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i added this code `pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Test"));
      pin.BindingContext = "Test";`  to my previous question so I have that now as well. And I would like to filter via my binding as well if that is possible.

Comment: then why not just add (p.Label.Contains(filter))?

Comment: My setbinding is going to contain a descriptiontext and not a "title", and I do not want it shown on my pin, but when u search (filter) via the searchbar then you should also be able to sort pins after the bindingcontext value

Comment: then try  ((string)p.BindingContext).Contains(filter)

Comment: That did it, thanks. How can I make a comment the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your BindingContext is a string, you need to cast it to the correct type first

You can do an explicit cast like this: `(type)object`

```
((string)p.BindingContext).Contains(filter)
```